# How to expand a complex typedef to its basic built-in form using clang?

Tags: c++, clang, libtooling

I want to be able to get the original type from the complex typedef.
I'm using clang version 7.1.0

Look at the code below

```
typedef unsigned int uint32;
typedef uint32 * p_uint32;

p_uint32 p_uint_var;
```

I can extract type of `p_uint_var` using `VisitVarDecl` like so

```
virtual bool VisitVarDecl(VarDecl *var)
{
    if(var->hasGlobalStorage())
    {
        llvm::outs() << var->getType().getAsString() << " " << var->getName() << "\n";
    }

    return true;
}
```

the output i get is this

> p_uint32 p_uint_var

what I would like to recieve is this

> unsigned int * p_uint_var

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that you are looking for is *canonical type*. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231080/what-are-canonical-types-in-clang), you can read about *canonical type* in Clang and different situations involving it.

Transforming it into the actual code we get this:

```cpp
bool VisitVarDecl(VarDecl *Var) {
  llvm::outs() << Var->getType().getCanonicalType().getAsString() << " "
               << Var->getName() << "\n";
  return true;
}
```

This code produces the following output for your code snippet:

```
unsigned int * p_uint_var
```

**NOTE**: don't make visit functions virtual. All Clang visitor classes are [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

I hope this information is useful. Happy hacking with Clang!

Comment: Thank you genius person. You saved me a lot of digging.